# Connection to database could not be established

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have configured cakephp3 using cake offical document on Centos 6. below are the php and mysql version detail,

```
php -v
PHP 5.6.40 (cli) (built: Jan 12 2019 09:19:57)

mysql
Server version: 5.7.25 MySQL Community Server
```

I follow the below doc to configure:
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/quickstart.html

While run development server now I am getting below error.

> CakePHP is NOT able to connect to the database.
>   Connection to database could not be established: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2019] Can't initialize character set utf8mb4 (path: /usr/share/mysql/charsets/)

Comment: Would you might provide your code so we can review it and find the possible error?

Comment: Hi @Gaurav, in the examples on site you linked, table definitions specify `CHARSET=utf8mb4` and `'encoding' => 'utf8mb4'`. I suggest you read about MySQL character sets. As a first step, change 'utf8mb4' to 'utf8'.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
<charset name = "utf8"> in /usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml with <charset name = "utf8mb4">.
```

its works for me.

Comment: better not to replace rather add the changes as a new entry in yml